# laravel template inside template

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to include a template (widget.blade.php) inside a template (master.blade.php) as below. both templates use sections named 'content' but the widget output uses the content from the master instead of the widget content.

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            @section('title')
            @show
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @section('content')
            @show
        </div>

        <div>
            @section('sidebar')
            @show
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

widget.blade.php

```
<div class="widget">
    @section('content')
    @show
</div>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    Main Content
@stop



@section('sidebar')
    @include('mywidget')
@stop
```

mywidget.blade.php

```
@extends('widget')
@section('content')
My Widget Content
@stop
```

The final result

```
Main Content
Main Content
```

Any ideas how to fix this collision?

Comment: How about renaming it to 'widget.content' ?

Comment: good idea but when adding multiple @include('mywidget') the override will happen again and will see the first mywidget content multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be fixed by using @overwrite instead of @stop

```
@extends('widget')
@section('content')
My Widget Content
@overwrite
```

source:
http://laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures